# Disadvantages to large resources in Java jar files?

Tags: java, performance, jar, embedded-resource

Is there any particular, specific disadvantage to embedding large resource files in Java jar files that are deployed? (Ignoring space, bandwidth, and other simpler issues with the consequently larger jar file sizes, of course.)

That is, would having large resource files inside the jars make class loading slower, take up more memory within the JVM, or things like that?

A jar file is basically just a zip file and should have a central directory so it shouldn't have to scan the entire file for loading specific file in the archive. I don't think the jar class loaders load everything in a file, only the ones that are needed, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Some frameworks are actually scanning the whole JAR file. However they are usually only after `*.class` files. The only disadvantage I can think of comes with the JAR manipulation - application (re)deployment takes longer, changing the resource requires re-deploying the JAR file.

Comment: @PavelHoral Yes, and there are also barriers to updating these when you have a software release process that gates outgoing changes. I was mainly trying to determine if there are fundamental efficiency problems in Java if large resources were jammed into the jar files. Scanning the whole JAR file should still be relatively fast if it uses the ZIP file's central directory rather than scanning the file looking at individual local file headers. (The latter seems to be strongly discouraged for this very reason.)

Comment: "if there are fundamental efficiency problems" - I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are loaded on demand.  For normal JARs, very little is loaded eagerly (unless there are specific entries in the manifest, and I'm a bit rusty there, but most people don't use them).  The JVM doesn't cache non-class resources in memory at all, so reading a resource from a JAR file is basically the same as manually reading an entry from a normal ZIP file.  The only disadvantages I see are:

1. The resource is copied every time the JAR is copied, even if it doesn't change, and
2. The resource is read from a JAR file (which is compressed), even if it's something like an image which is already compressed.

I think ZIP files support per-file compression algorithms, and support a no-op compression algorithm, though, so the second point may not matter.